# Having trouble trying to pass an id into the next form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, associations

I have a model of payments and visits. I have associated them in the model shown below. A visit can only have one payment.

I have it set up that a user fills out a visit form and then once completed is redirected to the payment form. What I would like to happen, is the for the visit id to be automatically passed into a hidden_field in the visit_id form on the next page.

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :payment
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :visit
end
```

It seems fairly basic, I just can't seem to wrap my mind around the associations correctly. I've searched around and seen a few people trying to explain it but whatever I try is not working correctly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be, in your `VisitsController`

```
def create
  @visit = Visit.create(visits_params)
  if !@visit.save
    render :new, error: "Something went wrong"
  else
    @payment = @visit.build_payment
  end
end
```

Then in your `visits/create.html.erb`, simply put

```
<%= form_for @payment do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :visit_id %>
<% end %>
```

It should work but it doesn't feel right from a RESTFUL perspective. A better way to do it would be to have, in your `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :visits do
  resources :payments
end
```

That will generate the following route:

```
GET /visits/:visit_id/payments/new
```

Then in the `VisitsController`

```
def create
  @visit = Visit.create(visit_params)
  if !@visit.save
    render :new, error: "Something went wrong"
  else
    redirect_to new_payment_path(visit_id: @visit.id)
  end
end
```

And in your `PaymentsController`

```
def new
  @visit = Visit.find(params[:visit_id])
  @payment = @visit.build_payment
end
```

In your `payments/new.html.erb` don't forget to put

```
<%= form_for @payment do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :visit_id %>
<% end %>
```

And there you have it... Let me know if that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: That makes pretty good sense, it's kicking out the @visit.payment.build though? Not sure what is going on there at all  
Error is: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry, it's an has_one relationship so it's @visit.build_payment instead, I'm updating my answer right now. Check out the docs for more info (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Auto-generated+methods)

Comment: Any chance you can give me a rundown of what build is doing?

Comment: It's simply creating a new instance of the relation class. When using has_one/belongs_to build_'other' will build a new object of class 'other' and set the id of the caller. When using has_many/belongs_to 'other'.build will do the same on the collection.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. Gotcha. Do you have time for another question by chance? unrelated to the previous one. I've got that working now

Comment: Glad to know it's working. It's better if you post your question in another thread if it's not related.

Comment: Done, sadly it will only let me post every 90 minutes, so this one killed that. I'll post what I'm trying to do below if you have time great if not no worries! Your help has already saved me several hours!

I may be going about this completely wrong

what I was wanting to do is something along the lines of the code below where when_appointment is a boolean. I cant make the code look right in the commment for some reason so i put it on a gist

https://gist.github.com/keithmackey/f3b879d348cc22717f74